# Is there a way to move React events to another file then import it?

Tags: reactjs, redux, refactoring

I made a calculator app for React practice and I was wondering if it was possible to refactor this event or move it to another module so that the code is more organized.

Since the event is connected to this.setState I am unable to think of a way to move it to another file.

Is it at this point where I would have to use something like Redux so I can more easily organize my events?

```js
onClickFunc(e){
    if(e.target.className === "number"){
        //Keep choosing firstValue if operator not set
        if(this.state.operator === null){
            this.setState({firstValue: e.target.value});
        }
        else{//If operator is set, add the second number
            this.setState({lastValue: e.target.value});
        }

    }
    else{
        //Can only think of a switch statement //e.target.innerHTML could have worked as well
        let call = this.state;
        switch(e.target.value){ 
            case '+':
                this.setState({
                    operator: function(x,y){return parseFloat(x)+parseFloat(y)}
                });
                break;
            case '-':
                this.setState({
                    operator: function(x,y){return parseFloat(x)-parseFloat(y)}
                });
                break;
            case 'X':
                this.setState({
                    operator: function(x,y){return parseFloat(x)*parseFloat(y)}
                });
                break;
            case '/':
                this.setState({
                    operator: function(x,y){return parseFloat(x)/parseFloat(y)}
                });
                break;
            case 'x^2':
                this.setState((value)=>{
                    return {firstValue: Math.pow(parseFloat(value.firstValue),2)}
                });
                break;
            case 'C':
                this.setState({firstValue:0,lastValue:0,operator:null});
                break;
            case '+-':
            //Make first number neg
                if(this.state.operator === null){
                    this.setState((value)=>{
                        return {firstValue: (-parseFloat(value.firstValue)) }
                    });
                }
                else{//Make last number neg
                    this.setState((value)=>{
                        return {lastValue: (-parseFloat(value.lastValue)) }
                    });
                }
                break;
            case '=':
                if(call.operator !== null){
                    let total = call.operator(call.firstValue,call.lastValue);
                    this.setState({firstValue: total});
                }
                break;
            default:
                this.setState({operator: null});
                console.log("failure");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I had also thought similar to this. But I realized that moving the events in different file was a huge task, and even I was success, later I reverted to previous code. So, I suggest you to stick them in component itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.setState` is for managing the current component's state.
So it'd be better to leave it as it is.

Instead, you can extract each operator handlers into either a separate files (or into one, depending on your requirement & time).

```js
handleNumbers = number => {
  this.state.operator === null
    ? this.setState({firstValue: number})
    : this.setState({lastValue: number});
}

handleOperators = operator => {
  this.setState({operator: operationMap(opreator)});
}

operatorHandlers = operator => handler => 

onClickFunc(e){
  e.target.className === "number"
    ? this.handleNumbers(e.target.value);
    : this.handleOperators(e.target.value);
}
```

And you can move operation implementations into methods and move them to different file(s) & export them.

```js
// You can move these to another file(s) and export each method.
const addHandler = (state, props) => (x, y) => parseFloat(x) + parseFloat(y);
const subtractionHandler = (state, props) => (x, y) => parseFloat(x) - parseFloat(y);
const multiplicationHandler = (state, props) => (x, y) => parseFloat(x) * parseFloat(y);
const operationMap = {
  "+": addHandler,
  "-": subtractionHandler,
  "X": multiplicationHandler
};
```

If you look at those `*Handler` methods, they take `(state, props)`.
The purpose is to be able to move operator logic outside of your component file.

If you wonder why, check this [twit](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/824308413559668744?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E824308413559668744&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.freecodecamp.org%2Fmedia%2F1c4129e6d55a4cee7d1883e97f2d207e%3FpostId%3D374f30401b6b) by Dan Abramov (a core React developer).
He explained the best.

[image: Best kept secret twit by Dan Abramov]

You can go crazy with more refactors but do so when it makes sense.
(*I can think of using a strategy pattern to inject strategies (*Handler methods) using High-Order components etc...*)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, its possible to move it as long as your code has access to the references it should operate with. You could put your code into another file and wrap it by a function which is passing the event and class reference. Like this:

```js
export const myFunction = (e, cls) => {
  let call = cls.state;
  switch(e.target.value){
    case '+':
      cls.setState({
        operator: function(x,y){return parseFloat(x)+parseFloat(y)}
      });
      break;
    .....
  }
}
```

And then imported the function to your origin file:

```js
import { myFunction } from './path-to-file'
```

And the in in your class  method:

```js
onClickFunc(e) {
  myFunction(e, this)
}
```